# django chartit no chart is showing, empty browser screen

Tags: django

I am working on a web app using django framework where there is a need to draw and show charts on frontend.
So i am using django chartit for this purpose, but when i run django development server, it shows nothing there is blank browser screen and no error also.
I am lost what i have done wrong.

Here is the view rendering the graph

```
from chartit import DataPool,Chart
from django.template import RequestContext
from django.template import Context,loader
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.http import HttpResponse
from graphtest.apps.graph_app.models import charttest
def chartview(request):
    powerdata = DataPool(series=[{'options':{
        'source':charttest.objects.all()},
        'terms':[
            'power',
            'time']}])
    cht = Chart(datasource=powerdata,series_options=[{'options':
                                                          {'type':'line',
                                                           'stacking':False},
                                                          'terms':
                                                              {'time':['power',]}}],
        chart_options={
        'title':{
            'text':'power data'},
        'xAxis':{'title':{'text':'xaxis'}}})

    return render_to_response('graph.html',{'powerchart': cht})
```

model for which graph is made

```
from django.db import models

class charttest(models.Model):
    power = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    time = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=10,max_digits=20)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.power)+' '+unicode(self.time)
```

and the template

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/highcharts.js"></script>
    <script src ="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type ="text/javascript" src ="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    {% load chartit %}
    {{ powerchart|load_charts:"container"}}

</head>
<body>
<div id="container"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

please help me out i am stuck for hours.
If any more information is needed please ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
<div id="container">{{ powerchart|load_charts:"container"}}</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This fixed the problem for me:

```html
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% load chartit %}
{% block title %}Gráfico gratuito{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    {% block javascript %}
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
    {% endblock %}
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div id="gratis">{{ data|load_charts:"gratis" }}</div>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

1.
Make sure you have put the highcharts.js file in your static and the path is correct.

2.
Try to oder code like these:

Answer (score 0):

Please confirm Jquery.js is front of highcharts.js

```
<script src ="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type ="text/javascript" src ="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js">


<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/highcharts.js"></script>
```