# Django chartit app not finding chartloader.js (Variable)

Tags: django

So I am still working on this issue and its shifted somewhat. here are the basics:

I've installed Django-chartit and its dependancies.

I've updated the settings.py to mimic the chartit example [here](https://github.com/pgollakota/django-chartit/blob/master/chartit_tests/settings.py).

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    ...
    'highcharts', # for chartit app
    'django.contrib.staticfiles', # for chartit app
    'jquery', # for chartit app
    'chartit',
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'static')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'staticfiles'),
    '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/chartit/static/chartit/js/chartloader.js',
    '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/chartit/static/chartit/js/',
    '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/chartit/static/',
)
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    "django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder",
    "django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder"
)
```

My Safari web inspector states: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: $ (chartloader.js, line 3)

And my server activity in the terminal states:

```
[17/Apr/2014 13:20:25] "GET /temp/herdAvgTemp/ HTTP/1.1" 200 1092
[17/Apr/2014 13:20:26] "GET /static/chartit/js/chartloader.js HTTP/1.1" 200 296
[17/Apr/2014 13:30:36] "GET /temp/herdAvgTemp/ HTTP/1.1" 200 1092
[17/Apr/2014 13:30:36] "GET /static/chartit/js/chartloader.js HTTP/1.1" 304 0
```

Which indicates to me that it is actually finding the js file, it just isn't sure about the "$" variable.

I've defined the problem a little further but unsure how to resolve this. I haven't been able to find a similar issue with chartit to compare.

Thanks for reading.
Mike

.

---

*********************** Older information below **********************

I am following the first [Django-chartit tutorial](http://chartit.shutupandship.com/docs/) and my browser inspector shows that it is looking for [a js file](https://bitbucket.org/pgollakota/django-chartit/src/cc4381e953fb4bc113d10eb71d5fb6f1fdfb29f6/chartit/static/chartit/js/chartloader.js?at=default) here (and not finding it):

```
<script src="/static/chartit/js/chartloader.js" type="text/javascript">
</script>
```

The file is physically located here on my Ubuntu/Django VM:

```
apps@ubuntu:/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/chartit/static/chartit/js/chartloader.js
```

This is causing the chart not to load. Chartit, Jquery and Highcharts all installed without error. I am seeing my template ok in a web browser session (with the exception of an error in the inspector related to not finding the js file). I am also seeing my data in a js array in the inspector so I'm thinking the apps are kinda working ok. I'm wondering how I fix it so its looking in the correct location? hardcoding an absolute path into my template seems wrong. I tried [this SO solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14354910/django-chartit-no-chart-is-showing-empty-browser-screen) as well with no change in error.

Thanks for any help!

Mike

Edit: my INSTALLED_APPS are:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'polls',
    'temp',
    'highcharts', # for chartit app
    'django.contrib.staticfiles', # for chartit app
    'jquery', # for chartit app
    'chartit',
)
```

I'm not seeing the other requested settings in settings.py.

*** Edit: because i screwed up the comment below, here it is formatted:

So I did some more research and I did not have anything written in settings below static_url, so I added the following based on some instruction, after rebooting the server there was no change:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/' 

STATICFILES_DIRS = ( 
    # '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/chartit/static/',
    '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/chartit/static/chartit/js/chartloader.js‌​', 
) 

STATICFILES_FINDERS = ( 
    "django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder", 
    "django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder" 
)
```

I also updated my template to test that out with no luck so far. My latest run at it:

```
<head>
    <!-- code to include the highcharts and jQuery libraries goes here -->
    <!-- load_charts filter takes a comma-separated list of id's where -->
    <!-- the charts need to be rendered to                             -->
    {% load chartit %}
    {% load staticfiles %}
    {{ testchart|load_charts:"container" }}
</head>
<body>
    <div id='container'>Test chart should load here. if its working. which its not. because you are seeing this message :(</div>
</body>
```

Comment: please share the settings of the following things: STATICFILES_FINDERS, STATICFILES_DIRS, INSTALLED_APPS

Comment: Thanks for your response, I don't see any reference to a staticfiles directory in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages or my settings.py so I'll need to do some more digging on that one.

Comment: *** Ugh, trying to insert line breaks not working for me *** So I did some more research and I did not have anything written in settings below static_url, so I added the following, after rebooting the server there was no change:<br>  
'STATIC_URL = '/static/'  
  
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    # '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/chartit/static/',
    '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/chartit/static/chartit/js/chartloader.js',
)

STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    "django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder",
    "django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder"
)'

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to run `python manage.py collectstatic`.

That solved it for me.